# Getting wrong result in Assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

```
   org 100h 
.model small
.data 
 var db ?
 msg db 10,13,'$' 

.code      
; add your code here
main proc
     mov ax,@data
     mov ds,ax

     mov ah,1 ;input 1st number
     int 21h
     sub al,48    
     mov var,al

     mov ah,1   ;input 2nd number
     int 21h
     sub al,48

     MUL var    ; multiplying two numbers
  
     sub al,48 ; going to ASCII value

     mov dl,al
     mov ah,2    ; printing result
     int 21h
      
     mov ah,4ch   
     int 21h
main endp
     end main
     ret
```

Comment: It is showing ASCII value of 12 if we multiply 3 and 4 
how to get proper 12 digit in assembly lanuage 8086 emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly mix two program models together. For **MZ executable** DOS program omit the first `org 100h` and the last `ret`.
Or use the much simpler **COM executable**, which doesn't use segment-switching directives `.data`, .`code`, and you don;t have to bother with segment registers. Its skeleton looks like

```
     .model TINY
     org 100h
main proc
     ; Program code must start here at offset 100h
     ; The first machine instruction.
     ; Put your code here.

     ret      ; A simple ret terminates the COM program.
var db ?      ; Data variables follow the code section.
msg db 10,13,'$' 
    end main
```

When you multiplicate both digits with `mul var`, the product is in register `AX` and it may be in the range 0..65535. Only in special case, such as multiplaying 2 by 3 you will get result AX=6, which can be converted to a single-digit result by adding 48 to it (not by subtracting).

For methods how to convert unsigned 16bit integer to decimal digits search this site, there are lots of examples here.